# Are two likelihoods statistically different?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, likelihood

Here is an example that will help me ask my question.

Let's say, I have the red and blue distributions as below, both of which are normal distributions (n = number of observations):

[image: Details of 2 distributions]

Then I introduce the below green point.  I'm interested in determining to which distribution it is most likely to belong.

[image: 2 Distributions plus a new point]

Visually, it's obvious it is more likely to belong to the red distribution.  Furthermore, I could calculate its likelihood for each distribution.  When I do, I get:

Red = 0.0807;
Blue = 0.0131

This further reinforces that the point is more likely to belong to the red distribution.

Here is my question.  I would like to also be able to quantify how confident I am in this.  What I had in mind is, some hypothesis test, in which the null hypothesis is that the point is equally likely to belong to either distribution.  The smaller the resulting p-value from this test, the more confident I am that the point belongs to the red distribution.

What would be the appropriate type of hypothesis test for this?

My first thought was to do an f-test using the ratio of the above likelihoods, with degrees of freedom of 49 and 21.  Alternatively, instead of using the likelihoods, I calculate the individual p-values for each distribution, and use those in the ratio.

[image: Individual p-values]

I also looked into the likelihood ratio (LR) test, but don't think that gives me exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: The visually obvious answer neglects a crucial datum: before observing the green value, what was the relative chance that it came from the blue or red distribution?  If, for instance, the blue distribution reflected 99.9% of people in a population and the red distribution represented the others, and you were to sample randomly from that population, then it would still be far more likely that the green value came from the blue distribution.  For the theory of this, research our posts about *Bayes' Theorem.*

Comment: Perhaps my visual is an oversimplification, so let's ignore it, and focus on the moments of the two distributions.  As for the "relative chance that it came from the blue or red distribution".  I don't have this, but assume that I randomly sampled 72 data points, and 50 of them ended up belonging to the red distribution and 22 belonged to the blue (like it's a supervised classification), and the data points were then used to build the two distributions.  Can I use p-red = 50 / 72 and p-blue = 22 / 72?  Once I have this, how do you propose I use it to determine my confidence level/p-value?

Comment: Confidence and p-values are not germane to your question.  Use your sample results as a prior probability distribution and apply Bayes' Theorem.